# Get dictionary that includes computed properties from Python object?

Tags: python, class, dictionary

Lets say I have a Python class containing a mix of properties created in the constructor and computed properties created using the `property` decorator:

```
class Example:

    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 1

    @property
    def bar(self):
        return 2

    def baz(self, x):
        return x * x
```

I want to generate a dictionary containing both kinds of properties, but nothing else. However, if I do `vars(Example())` I only get `foo`. If I do `dir(Example())` I get both `foo` and `bar`, but `baz` and loads of other junk as well.

Is it possible to automatically generate such a dictionary? I guess I would have to override `__dict__`? Perhaps by calling `dir` and somehow filtering out the unintersting parts?

I want to avoid having to enumerate all the properties by hand.

Comment: `foo` is an attribute, not a property.

Comment: not sure if will suffice, but all that "junk" starts with __, why not filter it?
`[i for i in dir(x) if not i.startswith("__")]`

Comment: "I guess I would have to override `__dict__`" - don't do that. It breaks too many expectations and too much code. They tried it with `namedtuple`, it was a bad idea, and they had to change it back.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was not aware of the distinction. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @JosepValls If I add a method, it would be included since it does not start with `__`. Maybe I should just filter out all functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental issue here is that `dir` returns:

```
Else, return an alphabetized list of names comprising (some of) the attributes
    of the given object, and of attributes **reachable** from it
```

But `foo` is *not* a attribute of the instance, it is an *attribute of the class* that is *reachable* from the instance, hence its inclusion in `dir` output but absence from the instance's `__dict__` . Check `Example.__dict__`. *everything* in Python defined in the class block will *belong to the class*. But in the `__init__` method, you explicitely assign `self.foo = val`, which assigns to the *instance*.

Consider:

```
In [2]: e = Example()

In [3]: e.__dict__
Out[3]: {'foo': 1}

In [4]: Example.__dict__
Out[4]:
mappingproxy({'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Example' objects>,
              '__doc__': None,
              '__init__': <function __main__.Example.__init__>,
              '__module__': '__main__',
              '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Example' objects>,
              'bar': <property at 0x104214408>})
```

Maybe the easiest solution is to take advantage of `dir`'s awareness of attributes *reachable* in combination with the following filtering operation:

```
In [12]: list(s for s in dir(e) if not callable(getattr(e, s)) and not s.startswith('__'))
Out[12]: ['bar', 'foo']
```